# How to bundle resources for ASP.NET MVC areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, asp.net-optimization

How would you do the resource bundling for asp.net mvc areas? Is this regulated by the ASP.NET MVC framework just like the `AreaRegistration` for routes?

I could make a `BundleConfig` class inside the area and call this from the global `BundleConfig` inside the `App_Start` folder but this doens't feel good to me.

I can't find any information on this subject. Any help our thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was hoping this was somehow more regulated - but after diving into the framework code the answer to this is negative.

What I decided to do is the following:

**Solution Structure**

- Areas:

  - Admin

    - RouteConfig.cs
    - BundleConfig.cs
    - AdminAreaRegistration.cs

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
internal static class RouteConfig
{
    internal static void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //add routes
    }
}
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
internal static class BundleConfig
{
    internal static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {           
        //add bundles
    }
}
```

**AdminAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(context);
        RegisterBundles();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(context);
    }

    private void RegisterBundles()
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);            
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Your question implies that you have separate scripts & css folders for each area? This is unconventional (though perfectly plausible). Or perhaps you have a single scripts folder at the route level and you have split that into sub folders for each Area? Either way you will have to do something only slightly different to get Area specific bundles.

MVC4 applications come with a static `BundleConfig` class that lives in the App_Start folder. The bundle is then initialized from the Global.asax. If you are not working with a MVC4 project either upgrade or just start an out of the box MVC4 project to observe the layout of these files.

Bundles are configured simply by declaring a virtual path, (from which the bundle can be referenced) then specifying the files you wish to be bundled. The files to be bundled can be specified by listing the filename explicitly, filename character matching, or specifying a directory in which all files should be included.

To begin with, I would just use this global `BundleConfig` to specify bundles for all of your areas. If this does not scale for you or becomes unwieldy, you can always break it out later.

Specify which files should be included. You should prefix the bundle's virtual path with the Area that it is for. Then it will be easy to reference using the Area name from your views - most likely your `_Layout.cshtml`.

For example, here we have two Areas each with distinct scripts: **User** and **Group**.

**App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        /// Bundle For User Area
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/user/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/User/myuserscript1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/User/myuserscript2.js"));

        /// Bundle For Group Area
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/group/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Group/mygroupscript1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Group/mygroupscript2.js"));
    }
}
```

You can then use the `Scripts.Render()` on your main _Layout.cshtml to render the correct Area bundle, depending on which area the user is currently viewing. To do this you first need to get the current Area like so:

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<head>
    @{
        var currentArea = (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]
                              ?? String.Empty).ToString().ToLower();
    }
    @Scripts.Render("~/" + currentArea + "/bundles/scripts")
</head>
```

#### EDIT

If you really want to manage your bundle from within your Area, then the Area registration would be a good place to do so. The BundleTable static property referenced in the BundleConfig is global so it can be referenced anywhere. This code compiles but I haven't tested it. It is for an Area called Test:

**Areas/Test/TestAreaRegistration.cs**

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/test/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Areas/Test/Scripts/jquery.js"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not the one for me. I don't want the global BundleConfig to do the bundling for the areas. I didn't made a choice yet on where to put the css & js resources for the area. This is a separate matter from where to put the responsibility of the bundle configuration. I do have a stronger feeling putting the css & js resources inside the area itself, it feels more natural to me. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated the answer with an attempt at configuring a bundle inside the Area namespace.

Comment: +1 for your edit. I decided to go for the solution in my own answer. This is more or less the same but it doesn't violates SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: I prefer this answer ( The Edited version). I have been trying different ways for two days. Finally this one solved my problem. In my case, in addition to the BundleTable in TestAreaRegistration.cs, also  I have to add the (test) to the    @Styles.Render("~/test/Content/css")  in _Layout.cshtml  file. 
Thanks